# Failed to load image

Tags: css, wordpress

i am using css for the first time and i have a small problem with image.
This is an example of my code

```
ul#navigation-menu li a.profile span { 
  width: 47px; 
  background: url(http://127.0.0.1:8080/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/navicons/profile.png)
       12px -59px no-repeat;}
```

The path is correct but i don't understand why it does not work since i did the same thing in Html with href and it's working perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: May be you'll also need to give `height` for this `span`

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/mywebsite /wpcontent/themes/mytheme/images/nav-icons/profile.png put this url in your browser and check the image is visible or not.if image is visible,url is not an issue.if 404 error code occurs,the url is invalid

Comment: the image is visible i try it !!

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `display:block` to your span.

You will also need to set the `height` of the span.

Span is as `inline` element so you can either give `display:block` or `display:inline-block` for the background image to be visible.

Comment: my css was working perfectly with a folder path and html page, but when i convert it to wordpress i get some problems with the link so i tested it in my browser and i get the image, i am little bit confused now!

Comment: Image is still not visible.